# Does it make sense to grow a cost-sink?

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, performance

Let's say I'm in an area of a business that is a cost sink: something like customer support. In this support realm there's a KPI that's based on Net Promoter Score. NPS is more or less used in industry to drive growth. Does it make sense to want to use a KPI to drive growth for a cost-sink end of the business? Is there any relevant literature on the subject?

Likewise, this is my first post here. Is this a relevant question to ask?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "cost sink", every part of a business goes into the business whether that's having enough support so your customers aren't annoyed (or even tell others you have excellent support) to having enough people in accounts to ensure your suppliers and staff are paid in a timely fashion. How you rate what to spend the limited amount of available cash on is why people get paid money for running businesses. There's no cheap or easy answer to that question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because while answers on StackExchange will ideally refer to sources, asking for relevant reading isn't on-topic on most sites including this one. Your question is also sufficiently technical that I feel it's outside the topic of interest for this site. [Project Management](http://pm.stackexchange.com/) *might* be a better fit, though I can't say whether your question fits that site.

Comment: A famous line from the guy who invented (and later regretted) coining the terms "profit centre" and "cost centre": "[The only profit center is a customer whose cheque hasn’t bounced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profit_center)".

Answer (score 6):

> Does it make sense to want to use a KPI to drive growth for a
>   cost-sink end of the business?

If you are a believer in KPIs and metrics like Net Promoter Score, then certainly you see value in improving them.

And even if you view customer support as a "cost sink", you might concede that customer support is a cost of doing business and growing customer support might be a cost of doing business well.

Given the above it makes perfect sense to improve your KPIs by growing this cost sink up to the point where the marginal value of further improvement is outweighed by the cost of attaining it.

While I'm not a fan of metrics, I have used similar arguments to get by-in for growing many teams that might fall into what you view as a "cost sink", and what some might view as "making our customers happy".

Comment: I like the last paragraph, the key would be gauging the improvement/cost equation

Comment: And I have to agree with you about metrics, I have seen far more harm done to organizations through misguided metrics than any other single thing.

Answer (score 3):

> Does it make sense to grow a cost-sink?

Sometimes it does, it depends what it is. Services which don't make a visible profit, or actually look like a loss can be essential to a business and give it an edge over competitors. Or they can provide rarely needed redundancy which saves a huge amount in disaster recovery situation. Two examples would be network redundancy and expanded support.

In the first I have seen one of my clients experience a power issue that took out 3/4's of their core hardware on a Saturday (servers, switches, backup units), and had them business-as-usual by 6AM Monday morning, most staff didn't even know anything had happened. I have also seen an office burn down and the next week the owners were advertising in the local newspaper that if anyone owed them money, please come forwards (they'd lost all their hard copy and digital records and had no current offsite backup).

In the second example some invest heavily in support so that clients have a minimum of frustration when they have issues. This can be THE major selling point for them in terms of customer relations and reputation.

Comment: And of course sometimes you need to grow the "cost sink" in order to prevent worse cost sinks or problems. For instance, one company I worked for experienced a period of phenomenal growth due to gaining several extremely large customers. It made sense to expand the HR staff first even though they provided no direct profit, so they could actually hire the people directly needed to support the new clients in a timely fashion. If the company had not done that, they might well have lost those clients because  they couldn't get the work they contracted for accomplished with no staff.

Comment: Yep, there are numerous possible examples in almost all facets of a business.